# Android Kernel Compilation Requirement

Tags: android, operating-system, android-hardware, android-kernel

I'm trying to setup the environment for Android compilation and the requirements suggest that I need to have 16GB of RAM/SWAP for compiling Android on a virtual machine.

I'm using an Lenovo R430 and it has a 4GB RAM. Can I go ahead with the compilation.

Answer (score 1):

You answered your own question, you have 4gb of ram and you said it needs a minimum of 16gb, now you can add like 20gb of swap, however it will be extremely slow.